# Why is <input type='number' value={var_name}> replacing all the values in a table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, lifecycle

I am trying to map out a number of elements in a table and each of the elements has  a specific value. Whenever i use value={inputArrival} or value={inputBurst} all the values of the specific column get update. I am attaching a screenshot. How to fix this?
[Screenshot of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVO8t.png)

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './tableEdit.css';
const EntryTable = (props) => {
    const entry=props.numOfEntries;
    const[inputArrival,SetinputArrival]=useState('');
    const[inputBurst,SetinputBurst]=useState('');
 
    function changeArrival(e)
    {
       
           
        console.log(e.target.value+"A");
        /*
        if(!Number(e.target.value))
       return;
        else*/
        SetinputArrival(e.target.value);
    }
    function changeBurst(e)
    {
        console.log(e.target.value+"B"); 
        SetinputBurst(e.target.value);
     
    }

   
   // console.log(entry);
    var ArrayEntry=[];
    for(var i=1;i<=entry;i++)
    ArrayEntry.push( <tr key={i}>                       
        <td className='row_editContent' >P{i}</td>
        <td className='row_editContent'><input className='input_edit' placeholder='0' type='number' value={inputArrival} onChange={(e)=>changeArrival(e)}></input>ms</td>
        <td className='row_editContent'><input  className='input_edit' placeholder='0' type='number' value={inputBurst} onChange={(e)=>changeBurst(e)}></input>ms</td>
        </tr>);

        return (
        <div>
            <table className='MainTableContainer' >
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th className='row_editHeading'>Process</th>
                        <th className='row_editHeading'>Arrival Time</th>
                        <th className='row_editHeading'>Burst Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    {ArrayEntry}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EntryTable
```

Comment: What are `inputArrival` and `inputBurst`? From what I can tell you are mapping the same value for each to all rows of data. You also are using the same `onChange` handler for each. Are these some local component state variables? Can you provide a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've provided the code. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I see, so `entry` is just a number passed in as a prop, and I'm assuming you probably want to only edit/update a specific row's data?

Comment: yes yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same single states `inputArrival` and `inputBurst` for every row entry of data in the table. Update so each is an array of strings, and update the `changeArrival` and `changeBurst` callbacks to curry an index to update. Use the mapped index to access the correct state and pass to the `onChange` callbacks.

```
const EntryTable = (props) => {
  const entry = props.numOfEntries;
  const [inputArrival, setInputArrival] = useState(Array(entry).fill(""));
  const [inputBurst, setInputBurst] = useState(Array(entry).fill(""));

  function changeArrival(index) {
    return (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value + "A");
      setInputArrival((values) =>
        values.map((value, i) => (i === index ? e.target.value : value))
      );
    };
  }
  function changeBurst(index) {
    return (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value + "B");
      setInputBurst((values) =>
        values.map((value, i) => (i === index ? e.target.value : value))
      );
    };
  }

  // console.log(entry);
  const ArrayEntry = Array.from({ length: entry}).map((_, i) => (
    <tr key={i}>
        <td className="row_editContent">P{i}</td>
        <td className="row_editContent">
          <input
            className="input_edit"
            placeholder="0"
            type="number"
            value={inputArrival[i]}
            onChange={changeArrival(i)}
          />
          ms
        </td>
        <td className="row_editContent">
          <input
            className="input_edit"
            placeholder="0"
            type="number"
            value={inputBurst[i]}
            onChange={changeBurst(i)}
          />
          ms
        </td>
      </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="MainTableContainer">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="row_editHeading">Process</th>
            <th className="row_editHeading">Arrival Time</th>
            <th className="row_editHeading">Burst Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{ArrayEntry}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit why-is-input-type-number-value-var-name-replacing-all-the-values-in-a-tabl]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working. But can u please explain what is the use of the ternary expression?

Comment: @AyushmanSinha Ah, it's a simple way to check if the current mapped index of the state being updated it the array element you want to update, if it is, return the updated value, otherwise return the current value in state for that index. Does this make sense?